# Scaling of photo on different screen sizes

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

We have a contractor designing our website. When viewing the home page (www.teacherspet.net.au) on a smaller screen, or when you resize the browser windows to smaller, the photo is cut off on the left side. I said your code should tell the browser to resize the photo to fit into the smaller window, but the contractor said that there is no solution to this problem.

I am not a web expert but I felt this should be a primitive problem that the modern web technology should have catered for long ago. I felt it was like my new Toyota Camry leaks water when it rains, and the car dealer tells me this is just the way it is and there is no way it can be avoided. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the height of the picture is constant, so effectively if you don't want white band on the size you have to cut the image. By changing the background size from "cover" to "100% auto" and removing the "center" of background you can have a resize able image. (in the css file)

```
.home_bg { 
background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat;   
background-repeat:repeat-x;     
min-height: 750px;  
width: 100%;    
margin-top:110px; 
background-size: 100% auto; 
}
```